# How to show the banks of a company at the footer of a report in Odoo8?

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I'm trying to show some data (phone, vat, banks...) of the company at the footer of the Odoo 8 reports. To do that, I create a view which inherits from the external layout footer and make the modifications. I'm able to see all the modifications I did in the footer of the report, except for the banks of the company.

This is my code:

```
<template id="external_layout_footer_fin" inherit_id="report.external_layout_footer">
    <xpath expr="//ul[@t-if='not company.custom_footer']" position="replace">
        <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline" style="font-size: 11px;">
            <li>
                <strong>
                    <span t-field="company.name"/>
                </strong>
            </li>

            <li t-if="company.street">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.street">
                <span t-field="company.street"/>
            </li>

            <li t-if="company.zip or company.city or company.state_id">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li>
                <span t-if="company.zip">
                    <span t-field="company.zip"/>
                </span>
                <span t-if="company.city">
                    <span t-field="company.city"/> -
                </span>
                <span t-if="company.state_id">
                    <span t-field="company.state_id.name"/>
                </span>
            </li>

            <li t-if="company.vat">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.vat">VAT: <span t-field="company.vat"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.phone">Phone: <span t-field="company.phone"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.fax">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.fax">Fax: <span t-field="company.fax"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.email">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.email">Email: <span t-field="company.email"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.website">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.website">Website: <span t-field="company.website"/></li>
            <li t-foreach="company.bank_ids" t-as="bank">
                HELLO
                <span t-if="bank">
                    <span t-field="bank.bank_name"/> <span t-field="bank.acc_number"/> - BIC <span t-field="bank.bank_bic"/>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Everything is being modified great, except for the banks. They are not being shown at all (and the main company has two banks assigned). In fact, it's not going into the loop `for`, because I can't even see the word *HELLO*.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you go to the companies form, there is a checkbox in the one2many `bank_ids` which says "Display on reports". Doesn't it make what you want?

Comment: Thank you @ChesuCR. I've realized that the problem was that I had created the banks in the record of the main company in the model `res.partner`, but surprisingly, banks are not updated in the respective record of the company in the model `res.company`. So when I added them in `res.company`, I started to see them in the report. It doesn't matter if I check the option *Display on reports* or not. The loop always shows my two banks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model what you are using is `res.company`. Make sure you added the bank accounts to that model in the company form. After that your code should work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_invoice_extend" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
<t t-foreach="o.company_id.bank_ids" t-as="obj_line">
                        <div class="row" style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 15px;">
                            - <span t-field="obj_line.bank_name"/>
                                <t t-if="obj_line.currency_id.name == 'USD'">
                                    <span>($.): </span>
                                </t>
                                <t t-if="obj_line.currency_id.name == 'PEN'">
                                    <span>(S/.): </span>
                                </t>
                            <span t-field="obj_line.acc_number"/>
                        </div>
                    </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!--
<pre>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
 <data>
  <template id="report_invoice_extend" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
<t t-foreach="o.company_id.bank_ids" t-as="obj_line">
   <div class="row" style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 15px;">
       - <span t-field="obj_line.bank_name"/>
         <t t-if="obj_line.currency_id.name == 'USD'">
           <span>($.): </span>
         </t>
         <t t-if="obj_line.currency_id.name == 'PEN'">
            <span>(S/.): </span>
         </t>
         <span t-field="obj_line.acc_number"/>
             </div>
         </t>
  </template>
 </data>
</openerp>
</pre>
-->
```